# Is there a flag to have Firebase Realtime Database NOT convert data to an array?

Tags: json, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the firebase realtime database and have some nested data, one of which looks similar to:

```
{
  0: {"Data"},
  1: {"More data"}
}
```

When I do a get with the firebase rest API, this will be returned as an array like:

```
{["Data", "More data"]}
```

My question is, is there a flag I can set to have Firebase NOT convert that to an array and keep it as a map? Or, do I have to manually set keys that are not integers. FYI, in this case I do pass in an array initially and let Firebase store it how it wants and create each index, I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no flag to prevent the array coercion, but a common trick is to prefix each key with a short non-numeric value.

So:

```
{
  "key_0": {"Data"},
  "key_1": {"More data"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank! That's going to be my plan moving forward, add some keys manually

Comment: thanks for the reminder...i did want to switch the correct answer as this one is more accurate to how i solved it

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do to change the form of the data in a snapshot.  The most reliable way *not* to get an array is to not use things that look like numbers as your keys.  That's why `push()` always generates a random string.  If you want ordering in your children, you should impose that through a child value instead of the key itself.

I suggest also reading: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I had a feeling there would be no way to turn off but figured I'd ask. Should be an easy change to my data to make it all work!